# Prove perpendicular in an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

> $AB=AC,2AD=DB$. $E$ is on $CD$ such that $\angle ACD=\angle CBE$. Show that $AE\bot BE$.[image]

Construct $\omega=\odot(BEC)$. Since $\angle ACD=\angle CBE$, then $$\angle DBE=\angle ABC-\angle CBE=\angle ACB-\angle ACD=\angle BCE,$$so both $AB$ and $AC$ are tangent to $\omega$. Therefore $\triangle DBE\sim\triangle DCB$, then $\dfrac{DB}{DC}=\dfrac{BE}{BC}.$

We can find $BE^2$ by Stewart theorem:
\begin{align}BE^2&=\frac{DB^2\times BC^2}{DC^2}=\frac{\frac49AB^2\times BC^2}{\frac13BC^2+\frac23AC^2-(\frac13AB)(\frac23AB)}\\&\overset{AB=AC}=\frac{4AB^2\times BC^2}{3BC^2+4AB^2}.\end{align}

To verify $AE^2+BE^2=AB^2(\Longleftrightarrow AE\bot BE)$ we need to find $AE$, but how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segment divided in three equal parts should bring medians and centroids into your mind.

Here is therefore a path based solely on Euclidean Geometry.

Produce $AC$ to $F$ so that $AF \cong AC$, and let $G$ be the intersection between $CD$ and $BF$.

[image]

1. Observe that $AB$ is median of $\triangle BCF$, and $D$ is the centroid of this triangle. Also note that since $AB \cong AF \cong AC$, $\triangle BCF$ is right-angled.
2. Deduce from 1. that $BG \cong FG$.
3. Use 2. and the fact that $\triangle BAF$ is isosceles to prove that $AG \perp BF$,
4. From 1. and 3. conclude that $\angle GAB \cong \angle ABC$.
5. Use the hypothesis and External Angle Theorem on $\triangle BCE$ to show that $\angle GEB \cong \angle ABC$.
6. Use 4. and 5. to prove that $\square BEAG$ is cyclic, and derive from this the thesis.

Comment: What does it mean when two angles or segments are connected by “$\cong$”?

Comment: @youthdoo it means that they are congruent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AD=a$, $\angle ACD=x$, $\angle BCD=y$.

Using sine rule for triangle $DAC$ gives:
$$\frac{AD}{\sin ACD}=\frac{AC}{\sin ADC} \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{\sin x}=\frac{3a}{\sin(x+2y)}\Leftrightarrow \sin(x+2y)=3\sin x$$
Then $$-2\sin(x+2y)=3\sin x-3\sin(x+2y)=-6\cos(x+y)\sin y\Leftrightarrow\\ \sin y\cos(x+y)=\frac13 \sin(x+2y)$$
Then $$\sin(x+y)\cos y=\sin(x+2y)-\sin y\cos(x+y)=\frac23 \sin(x+2y)\Leftrightarrow\\ \sin(x+2y)=\frac32 \sin(x+y)\cos y$$
Using sine rule for triangle $DBE$ gives:
$$\frac{BE}{\sin BDE}=\frac{BD}{\sin BED}\Leftrightarrow \frac{BE}{\sin(x+2y)}=\frac{2a}{\sin(x+y)}\Leftrightarrow BE=2a\frac{\sin(x+2y)}{\sin(x+y)}=3a\cos y$$
Let consider point $F$ on $BE$ such that $DF\parallel AE$, then
$BF=\frac23 BF=2a\cos y$.

Let consider point $G$ on $BE$ such that $DG\perp BE$, then $BG=BD \cos DBE=2a\cos y$.

Then $BF=BG$, then $F$ is the same point as $G$, then $DF\perp BE$, then $AE\perp BE$.